# Which discourses list the factors needed for becoming successful?

Tags: reference-request

I want help tracking down two discourses.

First discourse is where The Buddha is asked how long it takes to complete his training and he answers posing a counter question, then lists an amount of flawed qualities in a learner. It ends with him saying that if a disciple is of good quality the teaching can be reslized in 7 years... or in a day or so (this part similar to satipatthana sutta). I think this one is in the Anguttara Nikaya.

The second discourse i've heard claimed to list factors which lead to success in one's pursuit and the two;

- Thinking about the thing one is developing
- surrounding oneself with people who are into it

are included in that list iirc.

Thanks

Comment: Found the first one of them https://suttacentral.net/mn85/en/horner

Answer (score 1):

"And what is meant by admirable friendship?

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-ditthi/kalyanamittata.html